# Ignore Oath Request Throughput and Response Time through CLI in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

While doing Testing I need to taken the token from Oath API and use it in another subsequent API's which is successfully done. But when HTML report is generated through CLI the Oath API's Response time and Throughput is also calculated, is there a way we can ignore that request ?

Answer (score 0):

Add to requests [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) below them which will ignore request/response

```
prev.setIgnore()
```

> prev - (SampleResult) - gives access to the previous [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)

> Call this method to tell JMeter to ignore this SampleResult by Listeners

Answer (score 0):

There are following options:

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the Sampler(s) you need to exclude from Listeners/test results/whatever and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   prev.setIgnore()
   ```
2. Use [FilterResults Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) (available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) project, can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)), it allows excluding sample results basing on strings or regular expressions or time offsets or both
3. JMeter [.jtl result files](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles?src=contextnavpagetreemode) are basically CSV files, you can use your favourite text editor or tool like [MS Excel](https://office.live.com/start/excel.aspx) to remove the result entries you're not interested in